# How to download images from the database?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I need to upload files and images no larger than 2 megabytes in the database. But there is a problem downloading  images. All images that are downloaded break and do not open. No such problems with text files.

Result of the downloaded image:

> file 2.png

```
2.png: data
```

Uploading images this way:

```
module.exports.upload = async function (req, res) {
  const sysFileObj = {
    COMMENTS: req.body.COMMENTS,
    NAME: req.file.originalname,
    MIMETYPE: req.file.mimetype,
    FILE_CONTENT: req.file.buffer
  };
  try {
    await SysFiles.create(sysFileObj);
    res.status(201).json(sysFileObj);
  } catch (e) {
    errorHandler(res, e);
  }
};
```

multer:

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.memoryStorage()

let obj = {
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 2 
    }
};

var upload = multer(obj)

module.exports = upload;
```

And here there is a problem when download:

```
module.exports.download = async function (req, res) {
  try {
    let sysFile = await SysFiles.findById(req.params.SYSFILE_ID);
    var fileContents = Buffer.from(sysFile._props.FILE_CONTENT);
    var readStream = new stream.PassThrough();
    readStream.end(fileContents);
    res.set('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + sysFile._props.NAME);
    res.set('Content-Type', sysFile._props.MIMETYPE);
    readStream.pipe(res);
  } catch (e) {
    errorHandler(res, e);
  }
};
```

What am I doing wrong? Please tell me. I must say right away that I need to upload the image to the database without any links to any folder where the images will be stored.

**Note:**

> But, by the way, when I downloaded the uploaded image using “SQL
>   Developer”, the image opens without any not problems.

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: @SándorBakos `Fatal error reading PNG image file not a PNG file`

Comment: Are you using mongodb? If it is true, I think you have to save `FILE_CONTENT` as a binary data, let's try use `FILE_CONTENT: mongo.Binary(req.file.buffer)` instead of `FILE_CONTENT: req.file.buffer`

Comment: @hoangdv No, i am using oracledb + oracle-sage

Comment: I would check the row in oracle whether it contains my file or not. I would use some client that can export the file to the file system and would check first that it can be opened locally. If yes, you can at least exclude that the problem is around the upload. My other bet would be that @hoangdv mentioned, maybe it would worth to check / share the table DDL as well.

Comment: Only because of your last note I'm guessing your are having a problem induced by some kind of limit or encoding mismatch with your file buffer, stream or server/proxy which is serving it. So I'd debug the download `try`-Block. First set a breakpoint after `var fileContents` inspect `fileContents`. Check if its complete and maybe convert to its binary data server side (ie with `.toString()`). If here is not the problem do similar with the `Stream` object and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You must store image content-Type
And image data

```
const formidable  = require('formidable');
const _  = require('lodash');
const fs = require('fs');
// loading formidable library
let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
// taking file extension
form.keepExtensions = true;
//processing for upload image
form.parse(request_data,(err,fields,files) => {
    //if error when uploading image
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            err: 'Image could not bd uploaded'
        })
    }
    // validating all fields without image
    const {name, description, price, category, quantity, shipping} = fields;
    if(!name || !description || !price || !category || !quantity || !shipping) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            err: 'All Fields are required'
        })
    }
    // lets continue when there are no error
    // form have available photo
    if(files.photo){
        //1 kb = 1000
        //1 MB = 1000000
        // check image size
        if(files.photo.size > 2000000){
            return res.status(400).json({
                err: 'Image should be less than 2 MB'
            })
        }
        // there are no error found then execute it
        TAKING_AS_YOUR_VALRIABLE.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.path);
        TAKING_AS_YOUR_VALRIABLE.contentType = files.photo.type
    }
    // finaly save product
    //save it your own way

    const FINAL_DATA = {...fields,...TAKING_AS_YOUR_VALRIABLE}
})
```

now show photo code

```
if(TAKING_AS_YOUR_VALRIABLE.data){
    res.set('Content-Type',TAKING_AS_YOUR_VALRIABLE.contentType);
    res.send(TAKING_AS_YOUR_VALRIABLE.data);
}
```

Comment: I didn’t understand anything, but how will this help me with downloading the image? This is the same as installed in multer